# Run in your family

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

I am trying to ask the question "Are there any diseases that run in your family?". How is this best said in French, by a doctor to a patient?

Here is my best shot - "Est-qu'il y a des maladies de votre famille?". I have found "It runs in the family" written as "c'est de famille".

Comment: Cela ne concerne pas seulement les maladies, « c'est de famille » https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=c%27est+de+famille&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3 relate une particularité partagée par les membres de sa famille.

Comment: @Personne Indeed. I would even say that in English, "runs in your family" is not a great choice here. While it can mean having a history of disease, the idiomatic sense — une particularité partagée par les membres d'une famille — dominates. A talent for music, for example, "runs in the family". I think a doctor or medical form should say instead: "Is there any history of illness in your family?"

Comment: @Personne: Bon commentaire. Ça serait encore mieux comme réponse.

Comment: @HarryAudus — https://french.stackexchange.com/users/848/personne?tab=profile

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A practitioner would probably say one of those:

- *Avez-vous des antécédents familiaux ?*
- *Y a-t-il des antécédents dans votre famille ?*

*Antécédents médicaux* (shortened *antécédents*) can be translated by *medical history*, asking for *[antécédents familiaux](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant%C3%A9c%C3%A9dents_familiaux)* ou *antécédents dans la famille* refers to medical history of one's family members.
It can be used in a generic manner, or asking for history for a given  condition/disease such as in *Avez-vous des antécédents cardiaques dans la famille ?* asking specifically about heart diseases.

As mentioned by Oosaka in the comments, this phrasing is used only in a medical context.

Comment: *Antécédents* is nice. It somewhat implies the patient already has some disease so the doctor asks if the same disease or a similar one already appeared in the patient family.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and the only answer the question needs as stated, but I thought I'd specify in case the questioner (or anybody else who comes here) has a more generic interest in the phrase "runs in the family": this answer only applies to a medical context. If you wanted to say something like "musical talent runs in my family" you *would* use "c'est de famille" or a periphrase (like "on est trés musicaux dans ma famille" or whatever).

Answer (score 7):

*De famille* works in the idiom *c'est de famille* but not really the way you use it. That would mean the family as an entity has some diseases, not some of its members.

Here are a few suggestions:

> Est-**ce** qu'il y a des maladies **fréquentes dans** votre famille?

> Y-a-t-il des pathologies spécifiques à votre famille ?

> Est-ce que certaines maladies sont plus fréquentes dans votre entourage familial ?